# Jquery problem - menu will not work

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm trying to get the lavalamp menu working in a theme, but it just doesn't seem to wanna happen!

I've checked and rechecked the paths for the files, etc - but to no avail.

Any ideas would be appreciated! http://missjennifer.net/srini/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to use numeric IDs for your HTML elements.  [HTML element ids must begin with a letter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).  Since your HTML is invalid, your selector $("#1, #2, #3") evaluates to null and thus you get a javascript error.

My solution would be to give your tags a class -- like "lavamenu" and then apply a class selector for your plugin:

```
$('.lavamenu').lavalamp( ... );
```

**Update**:

Since you are also using MooTools, you need to use jQuery in noConflict mode.  You can do this using:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

then whenever you would have used the $ function for jQuery, simply use $jq.  Note that you need to invoke noConflict() after jQuery is loaded but before any conflicting javascript library is loaded.  More information on [noConflict()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict) can be found on the jQuery site, as well as ideas on [how to use jQuery with other libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

```
$jq(function() {
    $jq('.lavamenu').lavalamp( ... );


});
```

Comment: Thank you tvanfosson,

I've changed everything to use .lavamenu (css, script info  in header, etc) but still isn't working. Do I need to edit a jquery file as well? There isn't much left to try ...

Comment: Looks like you are including MooTools as well and MooTools is redefining the $ function so that it no longer uses jQuery.  I'll update with a suggestion on how to get your jQuery code to work.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, your element id's shouldn't start with a number. You've given ids of 1, 2 and 3 - try changing them to menu1, meny2 and menu3 and adjusting the ids in your script.

```
$("#menu1, #menu2, #menu3").lavaLamp({
```

Comment: It's not a "rule of thumb" -- it's a rule.  HTML elements must begin with a letter:  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function() {
            $("#1, #2, #3").lavaLamp({
                fx: "backout",
                speed: 700,
                click: function(event, menuItem) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function() {
            $("A").lavaLamp({
                fx: "backout",
                speed: 700,
                click: function(event, menuItem) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well change id to class

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $(".menuitem").lavaLamp({
            fx: "backout",
            speed: 700,
            click: function(event, menuItem) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you all, I appreciate your help - however ... I'm a little confused now with all the suggestions!

I've changed the javascript section as noted above, but it still isn't working ... sorry, very new to this lavalamp menu.

I'll have a look at the jquery files to see if I'm missing anything there. 

Thank yuo again `